# How to find the index of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON string as:

```
  var Str="[{ 'label': 'Month'},{ label: 'within'},{ label: 'From'},
         { label: 'Where'},]";
```

I converted it into an objects by eval:

```
      var tagString = eval(Str);
```

I want to get the index of month without a loop.

Is there a better way to get the index of an object in an array without using loops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not JSON. But you should use `JSON.parse` anyway, not `eval`...

Comment: I don't think so, with the given datat structur you need to loop

Comment: if i use JSON.parse it will give error like this                  JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Comment: Because it's not proper JSON format. It should be all double quotes and I don't think trailing commas are valid either.

Comment: if i use this   var tagString="[{ 'label': 'Month'},{ 'label': 'who'},{ 'label': 'What to do'},{ 'label': 'within'},{ 'label': 'From'},{ 'label': 'Where'}]"; it will also give the same error

Comment: i think, double quotas means: var tagString = '[{"label":"Month"}, ...]';

Comment: ok i convert it in json.parse successfully but how i will get index of  'month' fields?

Comment: In this case you can not. What you have is an array of objects and searching in an array takes O(n) or O(logn) if the array is sorted.You have to modify your representation, like '{"Month":1, "within":2,"Where":4}' but I am assuming this might not be possible for you otherwise you would have done it.

Comment: @vdua: "without using loops" and "without iterating" are not synonymous - built in functions allow you to express things without using `for` or `while`, as in my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If those are all labels, you could change the structure like this, so it's "An array of labels" which, in my opinion, would be more proper.

```
var Str = '["Month","within","From","Where"]';
```

Then parse it them with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), or since you are using jQuery, [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to get it to work on more browsers:

```
var labels = JSON.parse(Str);
```

`labels` should now be an array, which you can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var index = labels.indexOf('Month');
```

[It's ES5](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) and most modern browsers support it. For older browsers, [you need a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility) which unfortunately... also uses a loop.

Comment: if i use var index = labels.indexOf('Month'); it is return -1

Comment: @amol My answer suggests you change the structure of the data.

Comment: @Eric I cant change this data structure because I am using the visual search plug-in & it needs json object as I given in the question & fiddle

Answer (score 27):

Don't parse json with `eval`! Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good alternative to looping here:

```
var str = '[{ "label": "Month"}, { "label": "within"}, { "label": "From"}, { "label": "Where"}]';
var data = JSON.parse(str);
var index = data.map(function(d) { return d['label']; }).indexOf('Month')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxfdZ/)

Comment: But your solution is iterating the array.

Comment: @vdua: Yes, that's the only way to search a list.

Comment: That's correct, I misunderstood the question and assumed he didn't want to iterate the array. My Bad. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Note: if you want to get a specific item in JSON by its value, I came across this answer and thought about sharing it.

You can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

First as @elclanrs and @Eric mentioned use JSON.parse();

```
var Str = '[{ "label": "Month"}, { "label": "within"}, { "label": "From"}, { "label": "Where"}]';

var item = JSON.parse(Str);

item = item.splice({label:"Month"},1);
```

and Its ES5.

See the snippet code here

```js
var Str = '[{ "label": "Month"}, { "label": "within"}, { "label": "From"}, { "label": "Where"}]';
var item = JSON.parse(Str);

item = item.splice({label:"Month"},1);

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.findIndex() when searching by complex condition

[Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)