# Find where item is in JSON array by given value

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON is:

```
"people": [
{
  "id": "1",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "firstName": "Ashton",
  "lastName": "Negus"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "firstName": "Roy",
  "lastName": "Murrey"
}
]
```

I want to find where an item is by given value.

E.g. if I ask for id **1**, I will get 0 because it's the first item in the array. If I ask for id **2**, I will get 1 because that's the second item in the array, and so on.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please share your attempt first. It shouldn't be hard to write a *for-loop* and then `break` out of it if the value is found.

Comment: Convert it to array and find by id.

Comment: [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), my friend.

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559040/how-to-get-index-of-json-object

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL I'm bookmarking this link. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
var idToSearch = "1";
var index = people.findIndex( s => s.id == idToSearch );
```